# Variable Scope and passing Global variables

Tags: c++, global-variables, scope

I have to write a program that will calculate the value of e to a given tolerance. I must have a separate file for the function that calculate e and i must only use global variables. I can't pass anything back from my function. I am getting the same answers for my output every time, i don't think i am using global variables or calling my function right? Sorry in advance for the possible improper formatting for code on here.

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void find_e();
double tol = 0;
double e;
double euler = 2.718281828459045;
double diff;
string ans = "yes";


int main()
{
  while(ans == "yes")
{


cout<<"This program will estimate the value of Euler's number to your desired tolerance"<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Please input your tolerance: ";
cin>>tol;
system("cls");

if(tol > 0.0)
{

        find_e();

        cout<<"The new value of e is "<<fixed<<setw(12)<<setprecision(10)<<e<<endl;
        cout<<"The actual value of e is "<<fixed<<setw(12)<<setprecision(10)<<euler<<endl;
        cout<<"The difference is "<<fixed<<setw(12)<<setprecision(10)<<diff<<endl;
}

else
{
    cout<<"You can't have a negative tolerance"<<endl<<endl;
}

cout<<"Would you like to run this again? yes for yes, any other key for no\n\n";
cin>>ans;
}
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

and here is my function in separate file:

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


extern double e;
double newe;
extern double diff;
int n = 1;
extern double tol;

void find_e()

{

do
    {

        e = (n,(1+(1/n)));

        diff = abs(newe - e);

        newe = e;
        n++;



    }
    while(diff>tol);




return;
}
```

Comment: "and i must only use global variables" i feel sorry for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you, i know it is inefficient and "not right programming", but it's my assignment.

Comment: `e = (n,(1+(1/n)));` is actually treated as `e = (1 + (1/n));`, because you use `,`, which is treated as operator in here, and discards everything to the left of code on right side of the last ,

Comment: Good catch, it is supposed to be the pow function.     e = pow(n, (1+(1/n)));

Comment: But now there is no output...

Comment: `1+(1/n)` with `n` as an integer `>1` always yields `1`. Try `1+(1.0/n)` instead. Also, what's `newe` initialized to?

Comment: I changed n to a double for that reason, i also set newe = 0. Same problem. I know it had something to do with my function in second file, not sure what yet though.

Comment: Think i fixed it, i had my pow functions arguments reversed